# compute and confirm all payslips of a batch once

Tags: odoo-8

I am working on Odoo and I have generated payslips of all employees and now I want to compute and confirm all the payslips of batch once.
Is there any option in Odoo 8 ? 
I search a lot but i did not found any thing.
Is it possible or not in odoo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it totally possible in ODOO 8.0 as well as OpenERP 7.0 and you have develop  your own customize module from your side.

**Your customized Module can do the following things :**

1.Add new wizard and based on the wizard that  have 2 different field from the start date and end date or using as the accounting period and many2one field from your side.

2.Add the new for employees into that wizard as many2many for that wizrd

3.add the button for print your payslip

hear the payslip will print  based on selected date or selected accounting period and your selected employee list (as defined as many2many)